# How to turn www.mydomain.com/page/user/756890 to www.mydomain.com in PHP

Tags: php

How could I replace the URL of a string from this:

```
798| 451.263.160.11| CONNECT | http://www.mywebsite.com/pages/user/678976546789 | China | 22 min
```

To this in PHP:

```
798| 451.263.160.11| CONNECT | http://www.mywebsite.com | China | 22 min
```

Thanks guys :)

[NOTE: The text is from a file]

Comment: Set up a redirect in your server config.

Comment: The text is from a register file

Comment: I've been doing web development for nearly 20 years and I have no idea what a "register file" is.

Comment: hahaha sorry, im my mother tongue is spanish

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "register file", but it looks like you're trying to do a *regex replacement*.

```php
$input = '798| 451.263.160.11| CONNECT | http://www.mywebsite.com/pages/user/678976546789 | China | 22 min';

$search_for = 'http://www.mywebsite.com';

$output = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($search_for, '/') . '([^ ]+)/', $search_for, $input);
```

The code above will search for the string you provide, and remove all characters until the next space.

You can find out more about regex in PHP using the manual:

http://php.net/preg_replace

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php